# encode javascript array in php?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I tried to encode javascript array in `php` but doesn't work... i don't understand where is the problem:

This is my javascript code

```
var reports = [
               ["grup",24.5,101.6,"680 C.","680 C.",0,"N"],
               ["vul-Aca",4.501,-9.876,"192 C.","192 C.",0,"N"]
              ];
```

and i tried to encode in this way:

```
$file= "jsfolder/array.js"; //here there is only that js array
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
$json_string_array = substr($file_contents,strpos($file_contents,'['),-1);
$array_php = json_decode($json_string_array);
```

but i think that is a mistake :(

thank a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: your code works fine - https://eval.in/578567

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of semicolon from the end of the string too.

```
php > var_dump(json_decode("[];"));
NULL
php > var_dump(json_decode("[]"));
array(0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has extension to run javascript code in php.

install V8JS extension in php. Thereafter you can do what you are trying.
Get the contents from the file.

```
$file= "jsfolder/array.js"; //here there is only that js array
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
```

V8JS::executestring method then executes the string provided as javascript code. This will return an array as defined in php, and then you can continue operations in php